# MongoDB - How to pull object from nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to remove ($pull) an object that is nested two arrays deep, using MongoDB. For example, is there a way to do this to remove the `living_room` task from the `user`?

**Important: these tasks will not be in the same order every time. I need to find the tasks by _id, not by array index or taskName**

```
const user = {
    address: '123 example road',
    age: 23,
    taskSets: [
        {
            _id: '649376ee6d1efd215999881a', 
            name: 'Cleaning',
            tasks: [
                {
                    _id: '649316ee6d1efd215829882b', 
                    taskName: 'kitchen',
                },
                {
                    _id: '649316f16d1efd2139998884', 
                    taskName: 'living_room',
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: '649316ee3d1efd285999882d', 
            name: 'Mail',
            tasks: [
                {
                    _id: '1234', 
                    taskName: 'deliver',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work:

```
await db.models.Users.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: Types.ObjectId(userId) },
                {
                    $pull: { "taskSets.$[i].tasks.$[j]._id": taskId }
                },
                {
                    new: true,
                    arrayFilters: [
                        { "i._id": Types.ObjectId(taskSetId) },
                        { "j._id": Types.ObjectId(taskId) }
                    ]
                }
            );
```

Comment: try with this - `$pull: {
      "taskSets.$[].tasks": { _id: Types.ObjectId(taskId) }
    }`

Comment: @PritamJana thank you that worked! Will this theoretically pull any tasks from *all* taskSets that match that _id? If there is a way to certify that it will only pull from a specific taskSet let me know. Also if you provider your comment as an answer I can give you credit

Answer (score 0):

*"mongoose": "^7.3.1"*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ taskSets: [] });
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        await Promise.all([User].map((m) => m.collection.drop()));
        // seed
        const user = await User.create({
            taskSets: [
                {
                    _id: '649376ee6d1efd215999881a',
                    name: 'Clearning',
                    tasks: [
                        { _id: '649316f16d1efd2139998884', taskName: 'living_room' },
                        { _id: '649316ee6d1efd215829882b', taskName: 'kitchen' },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    _id: '649316ee3d1efd285999882d',
                    name: 'Mail',
                    tasks: [{ _id: '1234', taskName: 'deliver' }],
                },
            ],
        });
        // test
        const r = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: user._id },
            {
                $pull: {
                    'taskSets.$[ts].tasks': { _id: '649316f16d1efd2139998884' },
                },
            },
            { arrayFilters: [{ 'ts._id': '649376ee6d1efd215999881a' }], new: true },
        );
        console.log(util.inspect(r, false, null));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Debug logs:

```
Mongoose: users.drop()
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ taskSets: [ { _id: '649376ee6d1efd215999881a', name: 'Clearning', tasks: [ { _id: '649316f16d1efd2139998884', taskName: 'living_room' }, { _id: '649316ee6d1efd215829882b', taskName: 'kitchen' } ] }, { _id: '649316ee3d1efd285999882d', name: 'Mail', tasks: [ { _id: '1234', taskName: 'deliver' } ] } ], _id: ObjectId("649a95f8054e3a4521f13572"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: users.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId("649a95f8054e3a4521f13572") }, { '$pull': { 'taskSets.$[ts].tasks': { _id: '649316f16d1efd2139998884' } }}, { arrayFilters: [ { 'ts._id': '649376ee6d1efd215999881a' } ], returnDocument: 'after', returnOriginal: false})
{
  _id: new ObjectId("649a95f8054e3a4521f13572"),
  taskSets: [
    {
      _id: '649376ee6d1efd215999881a',
      name: 'Clearning',
      tasks: [ { _id: '649316ee6d1efd215829882b', taskName: 'kitchen' } ]
    },
    {
      _id: '649316ee3d1efd285999882d',
      name: 'Mail',
      tasks: [ { _id: '1234', taskName: 'deliver' } ]
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```